# Issue with passing string from Python to C shared lib using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm having difficulty passing string from Python to C by ctypes:

My C code(compiled into a hello.so)

```
...
typedef struct test{
    unsigned int    a;
    unsigned char*  b;
} my_struct;

int hello(my_struct *in) {
    FILE *fp;
    ...
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t%s\n", in->a, in->b);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My Python code:

```
...
from ctypes import *
...
class TEST_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("b", c_char_p)]
...
    hello_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("hello.so")
    hello = hello_lib.hello
    hello.argtypes = [POINTER(TEST_STRUCT)]
    name = create_string_buffer(b"test")
    hello_args = TEST_STRUCT(1, name)
    hello(ctypes.byref(hello_args))
...
```

I get the error:
    hello_args = TEST_STRUCT(1, name)
TypeError: expected string, c_char_Array_5 found

I tried to change c_char_p to c_wchar_p or c_char*5 or c_wchar*5 etc. Sometimes it can run without error, the first int parameter of the struct can be printed correctly, but not the second string pointer, the best I can get is just the first character 't' instead of the whole word "test".

BTW, my python3 version is 3.3.0

Comment: I don't know anything about  sending data between C and Python, but what happens when you assign name as `name="test"`?

Comment: If I do Python just as this:
        hello_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("hello.so")
        hello = hello_lib.hello
        hello.argtypes = [POINTER(TEST_STRUCT)]
        #name = create_string_buffer(b"test")
        name = "test"
        hello_args = TEST_STRUCT(1, name)
        hello(ctypes.byref(hello_args))

I get: TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance

Comment: I wonder if that refers to a bytes object `name = bytes("name", 'utf-8')`

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on whether you need the data type to be mutable (from Python's perspective).

If don't need the data to be mutable, then don't bother with the buffer constructor. Just pass the `bytes` object direct to the `TEST_STRUCT` constructor. eg.

```
from ctypes import *

class TEST_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("b", c_char_p)]

hello_args = TEST_STRUCT(1, b"test")
```

If you need a mutable buffer then you need to specify your `char*` type slightly differently in the `TEST_STRUCT` class. eg.

```
from ctypes import *

class TEST_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("b", POINTER(c_char))] # rather than c_char_p

name = create_string_buffer(b"test")
hello_args = TEST_STRUCT(1, name)
```

**`c_char_p` versus `POINTER(c_char)`**

Ostensibly, whilst these two appear similar they are subtly different. `POINTER(c_char)` is for any buffer of `char` data. `c_char_p` is specifically for NULL terminated strings. As a side effect of this condition all `c_char_p` objects are immutable (on the python side) so as to make this guarantee easier to enforce. eg. `{65, 66, 67, 0}` is a string (`"ABC"`), whereas `{1, 2, 3}` would not be.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `c_char_p` and `POINTER(c_char)`? I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: Just added an edit to clarify. The difference isn't immediately obvious and isn't really well spelt out by the documentation.